# Ruby Rally Rest API querying projects under a parent project

Tags: ruby, api, rest, rally

I am trying to query a list of projects under a given project using the Ruby Rally API.  However I'm receiving results that include *every* project under the WORKSPACE.  Not just those under the parent project.  Am I doing something wrong?  Is this a bug?

```
WSAPI version 1.43 
rally_api v1.0.1 ruby v2.0.0
```

Here is a clip where I set up my query object (using fake refs)

```
  #==================== Querying Rally ==========================
  project_query = RallyAPI::RallyQuery.new()
  project_query.type = :project
  project_query.fetch = $initial_fetch
  project_query.page_size = 200 #optional - default is 200
  project_query.limit = 50000 #optional - default is 99999
  project_query.order = "Name Asc"
  project_query.project_scope_down = true
  project_query.project_scope_up = false
  project_query.workspace = { "_ref" => "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.43/workspace/1234567890.js"}
  project_query.project = { "_ref" => "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.43/project/1234567890.js"}

  initial_project_query_results = @rally.find(project_query)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the code fragment you posted I don't see the actual query that limits the query scope. If query is omitted, all objects are returned.
Here is a fragment with explicit query:

```
rally = RallyAPI::RallyRestJson.new(config)

query = RallyAPI::RallyQuery.new()
query.fetch = "Name,Owner"
query.type = :project   
query.query_string = "((Name = \"My Project\") OR (Parent.Name = \"My Project)\"))"

results = rally.find(query)

results.each do |p|
    p.read
    puts "opened project: #{p["Name"]} owner: #{p["Owner"]["_refObjectName"]}"
end
```

On a side note, 1.43 of WS API no longer supported. To use ruby toolkit with v2.0 of WS API your connection to Rally may include this config property:

```
config[:version] = "v2.0"
```

Comment: Thanks nickm.  I added the line where I make the query using the query object.  I also pasted a debugger view of the query object at the time I make the call showing that the project and workspace are set.  I'll give a try changing the version to 2.0 to see if that makes a difference.